# Absolute value of two numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I want to verify and to check with you this inequality 
|a| > |b|  implies |a-b| > 0 
Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct proof:

$|a|>|b|\implies$

$(a>b)\vee(a<b)\implies$

$a \neq b\implies$

$a-b\neq0\implies$

$|a-b|\neq0\implies$

$|a-b|>0$

---

Proof by contradiction:

$|a-b|\not>0$

$|a-b|=0$

$a-b=0$

$a=b$

$|a|=|b|$

$|a|\not>|b|$

Comment: So we can say |a|> |b| implies a-b different from zero (without absolute value)

Comment: @sihou: Yes, but we can also say that $|a|<|b| \implies a-b\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you all for you comments and help

Comment: @sihou: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

$|a| > |b| \Rightarrow a \not= \pm b \Rightarrow a - b \not= 0 \Rightarrow |a - b| > 0$

Answer (score 0):

In fact $a\ne b$ implies $|a-b|>0$.

Just notice that:

- $a\ne b$ $\Rightarrow$ $a-b\ne0$
- $x\ne 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x|>0$
- Use $x=a-b$.